# How to connect to localhost using Python's paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, localhost, paramiko

I am totally new to implementing client-server communication and am trying to get started with a very basic example using Python's paramiko module. All I want to do is to send a simple string to my machine's localhost from one terminal window and retrieve it from there in another terminal window.

This is what I have so far:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(hostname='localhost', username='myun', password='mypwd')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo "Hello"')

print stdout

ssh.close()
```

What is get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ssh.py", line 13, in <module>
    ssh.connect(hostname='localhost', username='myun', password='mypwd')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 251, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 270, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 251, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Can anybody please advise where I am going wrong here? Why can't I connect to localhost using my correct username and password?

Comment: Are you running an SSH server locally?

Comment: Hm ... good question. How do I find out whether this is the case or not?

Answer (score 2):

This should connect properly if SSH is accepting connections on localhost.
OpenSSH does by default. Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config and your firewall. Another possibility is that "localhost" isn't configured properly in /etc/hosts. Try with 127.0.0.1 or ::1.

Note that to get the actual stdout, use:

```
print stdout.read()
```

Comment: I checked /etc/hosts which lists the correct config:

`127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost`

Comment: Should this worry me? `cat: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: No such file or directory`

Comment: May be ssh server is not installed. Install it and then try.